# How to handle US financial accounts after leaving?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, banking, cryptocurrency

I moved out of USA in Oct 2023 after living there for 8 years as a temporary worker. I am not working in USA anymore (physically or remotely). I have the following accounts:

- **Robinhood brokerage**: various stocks + crypto I purchased + regular dividends I receive from companies
- **I-bond**: I purchased [US Treasury I-bond](https://treasurydirect.gov/savings-bonds/i-bonds/) in 2022. It is earning interest. It matures in 30 years. I am able to sell it for some penalty.
- [**Shareworks/Solium**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solium): I worked for a public company. It gave me RSUs. These RSUs are fully vested. I own these stocks now.
- **Coinbase**: various crypto currency I purchased from time to time
- **Savings account**: some cash. Interest is being earned.
- **Checking account**: some cash. No interest is being earned.

Tax Status:

- 2022: resident alien for tax purposes
- 2023: (i think) resident alien for tax purposes
- 2024: non-resident alien

**Questions**:

1. What to do with these all of these accounts? Can I keep them forever in USA?
2. What is the best course of action if I want to keep them open in USA? I do not want to sell my investments or remit cash to my local currency.

I will talk to a professional but want to get some ideas before I do that.

Answer (score 1):

If the brokerage/bank where the accounts are allows you to keep them - you can keep them. You do have to update them about the change of your status by submitting a W8 form to supersede the W9 they currently have on file.

You may want to check your local laws where you are at as to whether keeping these accounts is allowed, and what reporting requirements/tax liabilities arise.